# Application not using xml in layout-sw600dp folder for tablets

Tags: android, android-tablet-layout

I am trying to use "layout-sw600dp" folder for changing layout for tablet. But it's not working. findViewById is returning null for views in "layout-sw600dp" xml  Checked manifest, ConfigChanges are ok. Tried on Nexus 10 and Nexus 7.
Please help in fixing this.

Comment: Well whenever I tested it it worked, and those tablets shouldn't be so old that `sw` is unsupported on them.

Comment: tablets are actually `layout-sw700dp` :)

Answer (score 1):

Check you are using the same ID which is in your normal layout.Dont change the id's while you are moving to layout-sw600dp.. double check your new layout-sw600dp.

Answer (score 1):

Same both file you have use same id of particulate View. Dont change you view id in layout-sw600dp.